# Specific user role can't log in

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I'm having a very strange problem: 
Most user roles can login without a problem (administrators, clients, etc...).

But users with the 'registered user' role can not login through the form. The login form does not respond. In the log messages the failed login attempts are not logged.

The only way the users (with role 'registered user') can login is through the request new password link.
So the user clicks on the link, receives an email with a login link, and when they click on the link in the email they are logged in. So than they can edit their account and even change the password.

However, when they log out again and try to login with the new password it does not work anymore, the form does not respond again.

The only way that user can get logged in again is through the request new password procedure.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

I suspect it has something to do with some kind of permissions.
Some of the modules i installed who could maybe give a conflict:
[Logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), [Registration role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

I did try to login with an email and username, same results for both.

But very strangely everything works now...
And i have no idea what i did to fix it.

Last thing i did was update every module and the Drupal Core.
And today the login form works again as it should...

I would love to give more information for future people experiencing this problem but frankly i have no clue what solved it.

Thanks again for all the help!

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below module :

1. [Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_reset)

> The password_reset module allows for passwords to be reset without
>   involving e-mail addresses through the use of security questions. This
>   module would typically be used on sites that do not require users to
>   enter their e-mail addresses or prefer not having to deal with spam
>   folder issues etc.

2. [Simple Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset)

> This modules simplifies the password reset process.
>
> Without this module enabled, core Drupal prompts the user to log in
>   via a one-time login form. After clicking "Log in", the user is
>   brought to their profile edit form where at long last they can change
>   their password.

3. [Password Reset Landing Page (PRLP)](https://www.drupal.org/project/prlp)

> The "PRLP" module enhances the original password reset landing page by
>   letting a user set their new password at the same time they "log in"
>   using the one-time-login link. It can also show a username and email
>   address field. The password entry field can be configured to be
>   mandatory. Other entry fields can be hidden through configuration and
>   the page the user is taken to after login can be configured.

Comment: Hello

Thank you for you're answer. But i think i may have not been clear enough in my question.
I editted it a bit to make it a bit clearer.
Cause i don't immediately see how these modules could help me out?

Greetings

Comment: Means in your site there is a registration form. After submission of form OTP send to the user email id & after click on OTP they can login successfully. But after logout users have facing issue in login with there existing password. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. The same goes for users who have an account already for a long time. They can't login through the login form. Only through the link you receive when you request new password. And this happens only for a certain role (registered users). All the other roles don't show this problem.

Comment: First Try to check "registered users" roles permission. Also check "Rules". I think this can happen due to some "Rules" for that role.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was kind of user error.  As on our other Drupal installations I had it set to except both Username and Emails ; and on the site with an issue only Username.  So the answer in this case was to make sure users where using their Usernames and not Emails ! [*Some* Users Experiencing Login Failures](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53353/some-users-experiencing-login-failures)

I hope this helps